# Magento shipping costs 1 cent difference by overview product

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

We have a problem at our checkout with the calculation of the shipping costs. We have set everything correct and shipping costs should be 4.95. We are using the one step checkout and at the second step shipping methods you find the correct amount of 4.95. When you look at the overview of the order, this amount suddenly changes in 4.94 (so one sent difference). See picture below.

[image]

Does anyone know what is happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is related due to the famous magento rounding bug:

Goto file `/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php`

Change the roundPrice Method to round with 4 digits:

```
/**
* Round price
*
* @param mixed $price
* @return double
*/
public function roundPrice($price)
{
return round($price, 4);
}
```

Hope this helps! Needless to say, at least dont hack the core - do a rewrite!

Comment: Dear Mischa, it looks like that is the problem. We still have to do some testing, but it looks hopeful!

Comment: Don't forget that fixing this right in the core will be broken right when you update Magento to a next version. But good temporary fix :)